# What is the reason behind splitting data using mix and max?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I know how Sqoop split the work among the mappers, it essentially uses this logic:

> SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM (Select * From myTable WHERE  (1 = 1) ) t1

Where id is the value defined in `--split by`. I also know that I can change this logic using a different logic using `--boundary-query`.

I am trying to see the reason behind this logic, because what happens if for example the values of the key column is not uniformly distributed, let's say for example if I have 10 records and I want to run this with 5 mappers (Ok, it's just an example):

```
id_column: 1,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207, 208, 209, 210, 211
splits: (211 - 1) / 5 = 42

mapper1 = from 1 to 42 ==> 1 record processed
mapper2 = from 42 to 84 ==> 0 records processed
mapper3 = from 84 to 126 ==> 0 records processed
mapper4 = from 126 to 168 ==> 0 records processed
mapper5 = from 168 to 211 ==> 12 records processed
```

Maybe I made a mistake in the example, but what I want to mention is that we will have unbalance work among mappers, with a few of records that will not be a big deal, but when we are talking about millions of records, it will definitely impact in the performance.

That being said, I want to know two things:

1. What is the idea behind the logic mentioned? (Maybe there is something I am not seeing)
2. You guys have an idea how I can build a workaround when we have ids columns not uniformly distributed like in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*What is the idea behind the logic mentioned?*

Idea is to use primary key as split by column (*if available*). Generally, **primary keys are uniformly distributed**. To solve the problem in a generic way  I can think of splitting the data in equal parts.Also, `min()` and `max()` functions are available with almost every RDBMS.

Say I come up with a new property which solves your problem with 2 mappers.

```
--mapper-range m1=1-10,m2=200-220
```

> mapper1 = from 1 to 10 ==> 1 record processed
>
> mapper2 = from 200 to 220 ==> 12 records processed

It would not much difficult for sqoop developers to override their range query for mappers using my *new magical property*.

---

But as we are talking about big data here, suppose you have 1 billions records. It is very costly to find the pattern of values of split by column as you need to process whole data for this. I guess nobody is interested in buying my magical property at this cost.

Please share your thoughts if you have anything better in mind.